# Form Controls VBA : Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a  label in my worksheet with the name "myPath" using form controls

And I made a button in the same worksheet that browse a folder and puts the path chosen in the label "myPath" :

Here is the code :

```
  Sub parcourir1_cliquer()
        Dim Repertoire As FileDialog
        Set Repertoire = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        Repertoire.Show
        If Repertoire.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("myPath").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Repertoire.SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "Aucun Répertoire Sélectionné"
        End If
  End Sub
```

It works perfectly on my computer, but when i tested it in other computer it gives the error :
Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" and selects the line :

> ActiveSheet.Shapes("myPath").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Repertoire.SelectedItems(1)

NOTE : My computer Has Microsoft Excel 2013, and the other computer Has Excel 2010 even though I don't think the error has something to do with the version.

Comment: What is `Repertoire.SelectedItems(1)` at error?

Comment: It returns the selected folder path ..

Comment: Rather than using `ActiveSheet` try qualifying your sheet (i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").`. Does **MyPath** exists in your sheet when you open it in another machine?

Comment: Can you write `ActiveSheet.Shapes("myPath").TextFrame.Characters.Text  = "TEST"` and see how it works.

Comment: @LatifaShi  I get that, what is the value of it though.

Comment: @Zac Thank you so much The "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") " worked for me .. Vityata , Nathan_Sav Thank you for your answers ..

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped